# Web Services on App Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, web-services, xamarin

I have an app in Xamarin and I want to make a Post of a web service .... on running my App ... this shows me a confirmation message (it does not go through the CATCH) but I do not enter the form in my Database ... any help for me?

my model:

```
  public class Infraccion
    {

        public int InfraccionId { get; set; }
        public string Lugar { get; set; }     
        public string Foto { get; set; }       
        public DateTime Hora { get; set; }      
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }     
        public string Observacion { get; set; }      
        public string Rut { get; set; }     
        public string Marca { get; set; }      
        public string Modelo { get; set; }    
        public string Color { get; set; }    
        public string Patente { get; set; }
        public string Latitud { get; set; }
        public string Longitud { get; set; }
        public int MotivoID { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioMovilID { get; set; }

    }
```

My code behind:

```
  private List<MotivoInfraccion> motivoinfraccions;
        private UsuariosMovil usuariosMovil;

        public NewInfraccionPage(UsuariosMovil usuariosMovil)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.LoadMotivosInfraccion();
            this.usuariosMovil = usuariosMovil;
            nuevainfraccionButton.Clicked += nuevainfraccionButton_Clicked;
        }      

        private async void LoadMotivosInfraccion()
        {
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            string result;
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://200.27.70.5/web_sit2/");
                string url = string.Format("api/MotivoInfraccionsAPI");
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "No hay Conexión...", "Aceptar");
                waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                return;
            }

            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;

            motivoinfraccions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MotivoInfraccion>>(result);

            foreach (var motivoinfraccion in motivoinfraccions)
            {
                motivoPicker.Items.Add(motivoinfraccion.DescripcionMotivo);
            }            
        }

        private async void nuevainfraccionButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (motivoPicker.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe ingresar un Motivo", "Aceptar");
                motivoPicker.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lugarEntry.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe ingresar un Lugar", "Aceptar");
                lugarEntry.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(patenteEntry.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe ingresar un Patente", "Aceptar");
                patenteEntry.Focus();
                return;
            }


            //waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;

            var infraccion = new Infraccion
            {

                MotivoID = this.motivoinfraccions[motivoPicker.SelectedIndex].MotivoID,
                Lugar = lugarEntry.Text,
                Observacion = observacionEditor.Text,
                Rut = rutEntry.Text,
                Modelo = modeloEntry.Text,
                Marca = marcaEntry.Text,
                Color = colorEntry.Text,
                Patente = patenteEntry.Text,               
                UsuarioMovilID = usuariosMovil.UsuarioMovilID,
        };

            //serializar el objeto infraccion
            var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(infraccion);

            //codificamos el objeto infraccion y lo guardamos en una variable content
            var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");

            string result;
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://200.27.70.5/web_sit2/");
                string url = string.Format("api/InfraccionsAPI/{0}", infraccion.InfraccionId);
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "No hay Conexión...", "Aceptar");
                waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                return;
            }
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;

            await DisplayAlert("Confirmación", "Infraccion Ingresada", "Aceptar");
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage(usuariosMovil));

        }
```

I noticed that the InfraccionId parameter is equal to 0 ... (is not this supposed to be autoincrementable in the data base?) [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bLTH.png)

Comment: have you checked the server logs to verify that the server is receiving the request?  Have you checked result from the server to see if it is returning any useful information?

Comment: Yes, I checked through Postman ... return my API fields @Jason

Comment: The Id fields are populated by the database **upon inserting them**. Before the save, the Ids are always 0 (or below 0 if you are creating multiple entries)